# Ошибка в BASH: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event - При использовании GULP 3.9.1

Tags: javascript, bash, gulp, babel, gulp-babel

Вот код gulpfile.js:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
let jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');
let babel = require('gulp-babel');


gulp.task('mincss', function(){
    gulp.src('app/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/css'));
});

gulp.task('minjs', function () {
  gulp.src('app/*.js')
      .pipe(jsmin())
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('source/js'));
});

gulp.task('esjs', () =>
    gulp.src('app/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('source/js'))
);
gulp.task('all', ['mincss', 'minjs', 'esjs']);
```

И вот код самого JS которого я форматирую с помощью плагина BABEL:

```
const { watch } = require("gulp");

let a = 1;

function Test(){
    array.forEach((e) => {
        e.classList.add('Lollilpop');
    });
}
```

Кто не понял что такое плагин BABEL - это плагин который форматирует тот или иной JS файл с ES6 до ES5

Вот мой package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gulp-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Artem Gerasimyk",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-buble": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-jsmin": "^0.1.5",
    "gulp-minify": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос `package.json`

Comment: Хорошо. Сделаю.

Comment: у меня эта сборка работает если поднять версию gulp-babel до 8: `"gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю много времени прошло и я нашел ответ после задачи вопроса.
И сообщение для тех, у кого может быть такая проблема.

Просто обновите gulp-babel до 8: `gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"`

***Спасибо пользователю [nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659/n%C3%B6rb%C3%B6rn%C3%ABn), потому что он в комментариях это и сказал ;)***